# SYSADMIN role and the ability to change database data

Tags: sql-server

Does the `SYSADMIN` role have the ability to access and change data in a database.  For example can this role directly access the file and change a record from $1 to $10,000?  Or could it create or escalate the permissions of a database user to then modify the amount? I am asking because I am trying to assess risk for a SOX significant system where there is a security issue with an account with that role but which only has the `db_datareader` role.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: A `sysadmim` can do anything. Literally ***Anything***. Only a very few people should have access to accounts with that much power.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the SYSADMIN role have the ability to access and change data in a database.

A member of the sysadmin fixed server role has full control over the instance, and is exempt from all permissions checking.  Also a sysadmin will always connect to user databases as dbo, who has full control over the database and is exempt from all database permissions checking.

The only way to protect data from a sysadmin is with [AlwaysEncrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) which encrypts the data in one or more columns with a client-provided key.

Comment: Thank you, I read how the SYSADMIN account is provisioned initially as the DBO. In this case the permission has been changed down to db_datareader.  Are you saying that regardless, the account will still retain dbo permissions even without the DBO role assigned?

Comment: Yes.  Sysadmins always connect as dbo.